# What templates can be used in the Kernel Configuration window?

Tags: front-end

This is the Kernel Configuration dialog from Evaluation → Kernel Configuration Options...

[image]

Under "Arguments to MLOpen" we can use several templates of the form `` `name` ``, which will be expanded by the front end to a certain value.  For example, `` `mathkernel` `` will be expanded to the absolute path to the kernel executable of the current installation.

**What are the templates that we can use and what do they expand to?**

Additionally, what kind of escaping and quoting can be used in this box?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

By experimentation, the templates listed below seem to be supported in the `Arguments to MLOpen` and `Launch command` boxes. For each template, a sample expansion is shown as produced by Mathematica 11 under OS X on my machine.

### Templates for Directories

- `` `baseDirectory` `` expands to `/Library/Mathematica`
- `` `homeDirectory` `` expands to `/Users/sakra`
- `` `installDirectory` `` expands to `/Applications/Mathematica.app/Contents`
- `` `jlinkDirectory` `` expands to `/Applications/Mathematica.app/Contents/SystemFiles/Links/JLink`
- `` `userbaseDirectory` `` expands to `/Users/sakra/Library/Mathematica`
- `` `userdocumentsDirectory` `` expands to `/Users/sakra/Documents`

### Templates for Files

- `` `executable` `` expands to `wolfram`
- `` `java` `` expands to `/Applications/Mathematica.app/Contents/SystemFiles/Java/MacOSX-x86-64/bin/java`
- `` `javaw` `` expands to `/Applications/Mathematica.app/Contents/SystemFiles/Java/MacOSX-x86-64/bin/java`
- `` `jlinkjar` `` expands to `/Applications/Mathematica.app/Contents/SystemFiles/Links/JLink/JLink.jar`
- `` `mathkernel` `` expands to `/Applications/Mathematica.app/Contents/MacOS/WolframKernel`
- `` `mathssh` `` expands to `/Applications/Mathematica.app/Contents/SystemFiles/Java/WolframSSH.jar`
- `` `wolframkernel` `` expands to `/Applications/Mathematica.app/Contents/MacOS/WolframKernel`
- `` `wolframssh` `` expands to `/Applications/Mathematica.app/Contents/SystemFiles/Java/WolframSSH.jar`

### Templates for Environment

- `` `ipaddress` `` expands to `192.168.1.11`
- `` `machinename` `` expands to `host.example.com`
- `` `username` `` expands to `sakra`

### Templates for WSTP

The expansion of the following templates depends on the WSTP link actually created by the options entered in the `Arguments to MLOpen` box.

#### Templates for a `TCPIP` WSTP link

- `` `linkname` `` expands to `54656@192.168.1.11,54657@192.168.1.11`
- `` `dataport` `` expands to `54656@192.168.1.11`
- `` `messageport` `` expands to `54657@192.168.1.11`
- `` `socketname` `` expands to `54656`

#### Templates for a `SharedMemory` WSTP link

- `` `linkname` `` expands to `dr6hn_shm`
- `` `dataport` `` expands to `dr6hn_shm`
- `` `messageport` `` expands to empty string
- `` `socketname` `` expands to `dr6hn_shm`

### Quoting

Under OS X and Linux both single quotes and double quotes can be used for quoting arguments in the expected way.

Under Windows the launch command is passed to `cmd.exe` in the following way:

```
C:\Windows\system32\cmd.exe /c "launch command"
```

That means that the quoting rules for `cmd.exe /c` apply, i.e. double quotes work as expected.